# Serilog an entity serilog cycles in the object graph / loops infinitely

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

Similar to [issue 98](https://github.com/datalust/serilog-sinks-seq/issues/98)

I have a `SeriLog ILogger` behavior in an `IPipelineBehavior` that logs Queries and Commands in the API

The code that logs is shown below:

```
public class LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    {
        private readonly ILogger<LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> _logger;
        public LoggingBehavior(ILogger<LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> logger) => _logger = logger;

        public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("----- Handling command {CommandName} ({@Command})", request.GetGenericTypeName(), request);
            var response = await next();
            _logger.LogInformation("----- Command {CommandName} handled - response: {@Response}", request.GetGenericTypeName(), response);

            return response;
        }
    }
```

The entity that is being returned:

```
public partial class Vehicle: Entity, IAggregateRoot
    {

        public int VehicleOrderId { get; private set; }

        public int VehicleStatusId { get; private set; }

        public int DepartmentId { get; private set; }

        //TODO: Validate that the number ends with "FS"
        public string GG_Registration_Number { get; private set; }


        //TODO: This required but it must be assigned by Licensing therefore use Bootstrap to Validate this when Adding it to the system [Required]
        public string Registration_Number { get; private set; }

       
        public string Make { get; private set; }

        
        public string Model { get; private set; }

        public int Year_Model { get; private set; }

        public string Chassis_Number { get; private set; }

        public string Engine_Number { get; private set; }


        public string Created_By { get; private set; }

        public DateTime Date_Created { get; private set; }

        public string Updated_By { get; private set; }

        public DateTime Date_Updated { get; private set; }

        public VehicleOrder VehicleOrder { get; private set; }

        public Department Department { get; private set; }

        public VehicleStatus VehicleStatus { get; private set; }

        public virtual VehicleDetail VehicleDetail { get; private set; }

        public virtual VehiclePreparationChecklist PreparationChecklist { get; private set; }

        public virtual List<VehicleRequiredAccessory> RequiredAccessories { get; private set; }

        public virtual List<VehicleFittedAccessory> FittedAccessories { get; private set; }

        public virtual VehicleAllocation VehicleAllocation { get; private set; }
```

The data that is being returned comes from this `GetVehiclesQuery`:

```
     public async Task<IEnumerable<Vehicle>> GetVehiclesAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Vehicles.Include(v=>v.VehicleOrder)
                                            .Include(v=>v.Department)
                                            .Include(v=>v.FittedAccessories)
                                                .ThenInclude(fa=>fa.FittedAccessory)
                                            .Include(v=>v.VehicleStatus)
                                            .AsNoTracking()
                                            .ToArrayAsync();
        }
```

but the `_logger.LogInformation` loops infinitely on the entity as shown below.

```
 [{"Id": 1, "VehicleOrderId": 1, "DepartmentId": 3, "Vehicle_Status": "inpreparation", "GG_Registration_Number": "GBL200FS", "Registration_Number": "FJS7501FS", "Make": "VW", "Model": "Polo", "Year_Model": 2010, "Chassis_Number": "CGGG-VVV", "Engine_Number": "Engine_Number3", "Total_Vehicle_Price": 52000.00, "Department": {"Id": 3, "Department_Code": "DOJ001", "Department_Name": "Department of Justice", "Physical_Address": {"Street": "580 Section A", "Surburb": "Botshabelo", "City": "Bloemfontein", "Province": "Free State", "Postal_Code": "9781", "$type": "AddressDto"}, "Postal_Address": {"Street": "580 Section A", "Surburb": "Botshabelo", "City": "Bloemfontein", "Province": "Free State", "Postal_Code": "9781", "$type": "AddressDto"}, "$type": "DepartmentDto"}, "VehicleOrder": {"Id": 1, "VehicleRequestLetterId": 1, "Order_Number": "HDKDKD", "Order_Date": "2020-11-14T08:32:22.5473019", "Order_Unit_Price": 52000.00, "Order_Quantity": 5, "Total_Order_Price": 260000.00, "Order_Documents": "Ddocument1", "VehicleRequestLetter": null, "Vehicles": [{"Id": 1, "VehicleOrderId": 1, "DepartmentId": 3, "Vehicle_Status": "inpreparation", "GG_Registration_Number": "GBL200FS", "Registration_Number": "FJS7501FS", "Make": "VW", "Model": "Polo", "Year_Model": 2010, "Chassis_Number": "CGGG-VVV", "Engine_Number": "Engine_Number3", "Total_Vehicle_Price": 52000.00, "Department": {"Id": 3, "Department_Code": "DOJ001", "Department_Name": "Department of Justice", "Physical_Address": {"Street": "580 Section A", "Surburb": "Botshabelo", "City": "Bloemfontein", "Province": "Free State", "Postal_Code": "9781", "$type": "AddressDto"}, "Postal_Address": {"Street": "580 Section A", "Surburb": "Botshabelo", "City": "Bloemfontein", "Province": "Free State", "Postal_Code": "9781", "$type": "AddressDto"}, "$type": "DepartmentDto"}, "VehicleOrder": {"Id": 1, "VehicleRequestLetterId": 1, "Order_Number": "HDKDKD", "Order_Date": "2020-11-14T08:32:22.5473019", "Order_Unit_Price": 52000.00, "Order_Quantity": 5, "Total_Order_Price": 260000.00, "Order_Documents": "Ddocument1", "VehicleRequestLetter": null, "Vehicles": [{"Id": 1, "VehicleOrderId": 1, "DepartmentId": 3, "Vehicle_Status": "inpreparation", "GG_Registration_Number": "GBL200FS", "Registration_Number": "FJS7501FS", "Make": "VW", "Model": "Polo", "Year_Model": 2010, "Chassis_Number": "CGGG-VVV", "Engine_Number": "Engine_Number3", "Total_Vehicle_Price": 52000.00, "Department": {"Id": 3, "Department_Code": "DOJ001", "Department_Name": "Department of Justice", "Physical_Address": {"Street": null, "Surburb": null, "City": null, "Province": null, "Postal_Code": null, "$type": "AddressDto"}, "Postal_Address": {"Street": null, "Surburb": null, "City": null, "Province": null, "Postal_Code": null, "$type": "AddressDto"}, "$type": "DepartmentDto"}, "VehicleOrder": {"Id": 1, "VehicleRequestLetterId": 1, "Order_Number": "HDKDKD", "Order_Date": "2020-11-14T08:32:22.5473019", "Order_Unit_Price": 52000.00, "Order_Quantity": 5, "Total_Order_Price": 260000.00, "Order_Documents": "Ddocument1", "VehicleRequestLetter": null, "Vehicles": [null], "$type": "VehicleOrderDto"}, "$type": "VehicleDto"}], "$type": "VehicleOrderDto"}, "$type": "VehicleDto"}], "$type": "VehicleOrderDto"}, "$type": "VehicleDto"}, {"Id": 2, "VehicleOrderId": 1, "DepartmentId": 2, "Vehicle_Status": "inpreparation", "GG_Registration_Number": "GBJ568FS", "Registration_Number": "HJK114FS", "Make": "Toyata", "Model": "Hillux", "Year_Model": 2005, "Chassis_Number": "785FF-GGG=RR781-KIL99", "Engine_Number": "Engine_Number2", "Total_Vehicle_Price": 52000.00, "Department": {"Id": 2, "Department_Code": "PRT001", "Department_Name": "Police Roads and Transport", "Physical_Address": null, "Postal_Address": null, "$type": "DepartmentDto"}, "VehicleOrder": {"Id": 1, "VehicleRequestLetterId": 1, "Order_Number": "HDKDKD", "Order_Date": "2020-11-14T08:32:22.5473019", "Order_Unit_Price": 52000.00, "Order_Quantity": 5, "Total_Order_Price": 260000.00, "Order_Documents": "Ddocument1", "VehicleRequestLetter": null, "Vehicles": [{"Id": 2, "VehicleOrderId": 1, "DepartmentId": 2, "Vehicle_Status": "inpreparation", "GG_Registration_Number": "GBJ568FS", "Registration_Number": "HJK114FS", "Make": "Toyata", "Model": "Hillux", "Year_Model": 2005, "Chassis_Number": "785FF-GGG=RR781-KIL99", "Engine_Number": "Engine_Number2", "Total_Vehicle_Price": 52000.00, "Department": {"Id": 2, "Department_Code": "PRT001", "Department_Name": "Police Roads and Transport", "Physical_Address": null, "Postal_Address": null, "$type": "DepartmentDto"}, "VehicleOrder": {"Id": 1, "VehicleRequestLetterId": 1, "Order_Number": "HDKDKD", "Order_Date": "2020-11-14T08:32:22.5473019", "Order_Unit_Price": 52000.00, "Order_Quantity": 5, "Total_Order_Price": 260000.00, "Order_Documents": "Ddocument1", "VehicleRequestLetter": null, "Vehicles": [{"Id": 2, "VehicleOrderId": 1, "DepartmentId": 2, "Vehicle_Status": "inpreparation", "GG_Registration_Number": "GBJ568FS", "Registration_Number": "HJK114FS", "Make": "Toyata", "Model": "Hillux", "Year_Model": 2005, "Chassis_Number": "785FF-GGG=RR781-KIL99", "Engine_Number": "Engine_Number2", "Total_Vehicle_Price": 52000.00, "Department": {"Id": 2, "Department_Code": "PRT001", "Department_Name": "Police Roads and Transport", "Physical_Address": null, "Postal_Address": null, "$type": "DepartmentDto"}, "VehicleOrder": {"Id": 1, "VehicleRequestLetterId": 1, "Order_Number": "HDKDKD", "Order_Date": "2020-11-14T08:32:22.5473019", "Order_Unit_Price": 52000.00, "Order_Quantity": 5, "Total_Order_Price": 260000.00, "Order_Documents": "Ddocument1", "VehicleRequestLetter": null, "Vehicles": [null], "$type": "VehicleOrderDto"}, "$type": "VehicleDto"}], "$type": "VehicleOrderDto"}, "$type": "VehicleDto"}], "$type": "VehicleOrderDto"}, "$type": "VehicleDto"}, {"Id": 3, "VehicleOrderId": 1, "DepartmentId": 1, "Vehicle_Status": "inpreparation", "GG_Registration_Number": "GRB552FS", "Registration_Number": "FXT5013FS", "Make": "VW", "Model": "Polo", "Year_Model": 2010, "Chassis_Number": "CGGG-VVV", "Engine_Number": "Engine_Number", "Total_Vehicle_Price": 52000.00, "Department": {"Id": 1, "Department_Code": "DTA001", "Department_Name": "Destia", "Physical_Address": null, "Postal_Address": null, "$type": "DepartmentDto"}, "VehicleOrder": {"Id": 1, "VehicleRequestLetterId": 1, "Order_Number": "HDKDKD", "Order_Date": "2020-11-14T08:32:22.5473019", "Order_Unit_Price": 52000.00, "Order_Quantity": 5, "Total_Order_Price": 260000.00, "Order_Documents": "Ddocument1", "VehicleRequestLetter": null, "Vehicles": [{"Id": 3, "VehicleOrderId": 1, "DepartmentId": 1, "Vehicle_Status": "inpreparation", "GG_Registration_Number": "GRB552FS", "Registration_Number": "FXT5013FS", "Make": "VW", "Model": "Polo", "Year_Model": 2010, "Chassis_Number": "CGGG-VVV", "Engine_Number": "Engine_Number", "Total_Vehicle_Price": 52000.00, "Department": {"Id": 1, "Department_Code": "DTA001", "Department_Name": "Destia", "Physical_Address": null, "Postal_Address": null, "$type": "DepartmentDto"}, "VehicleOrder": {"Id": 1, "VehicleRequestLetterId": 1, "Order_Number": "HDKDKD", "Order_Date": "2020-11-14T08:32:22.5473019", "Order_Unit_Price": 52000.00, "Order_Quantity": 5, "Total_Order_Price": 260000.00, "Order_Documents": "Ddocument1", "VehicleRequestLetter": null, "Vehicles": [{"Id": 3, "VehicleOrderId": 1, "DepartmentId": 1, "Vehicle_Status": "inpreparation", "GG_Registration_Number": "GRB552FS", "Registration_Number": "FXT5013FS", "Make": "VW", "Model": "Polo", "Year_Model": 2010, "Chassis_Number": "CGGG-VVV", "Engine_Number": "Engine_Number", "Total_Vehicle_Price": 52000.00, "Department": {"Id": 1, "Department_Code": "DTA001", "Department_Name": "Destia", "Physical_Address": null, "Postal_Address": null, "$type": "DepartmentDto"}, "VehicleOrder": {"Id": 1, "VehicleRequestLetterId": 1, "Order_Number": "HDKDKD", "Order_Date": "2020-11-14T08:32:22.5473019", "Order_Unit_Price": 52000.00, "Order_Quantity": 5, "Total_Order_Price": 260000.00, "Order_Documents": "Ddocument1", "VehicleRequestLetter": null, "Vehicles": [null], "$type": "VehicleOrderDto"}, "$type": "VehicleDto"}], "$type": "VehicleOrderDto"}, "$type": "VehicleDto"}], "$type": "VehicleOrderDto"}, "$type": "VehicleDto"}]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, make sure you clearly state what your question is.

Comment: Can you please post the log message as text, rather than as an image? It's very hard to work out which bit of it is getting repeated, without being able to format it properly.

Comment: So in your GetVahiclesQuery command you have a loop, and it's ToString() is overriden to actually return a Json, so you could just add [JsonIgnore] at some property there to break the loop, if you could provide GetVahiclesQuery definition, i could suggest what property to Ignore

Comment: Each entry is unique in the logger file.  No looping.